# Can I write a stable MystCraft age that has dense ores?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods, minecraft-mystcraft

I've been trying to write the perfect MystCraft age for me to plunder for its resources, but unfortunately including the Dense Ores symbol invariably seems to make it unstable. At least I get hit with a debuff when I travel there, which I'm pretty sure indicates instability.

Is there a combination of symbols or some sort of mechanic that I can use to get me that stable mining age? Failing that, is it possible to write one that's at least *structurally* stable? I.e. no decay blocks, meteorite strikes, or anything of that kidney. I can live with debuffs. Or rather, my quarries can.

I know I can probably do it via cheating or admin commands, but that doesn't count.

Comment: You realize this is exactly what [Ghen](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/90486/is-there-any-explanation-for-the-island-of-myst-or-how-the-player-arrives-there) was doing to his Ages in-canon.  [It didn't work out well for him.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YulhuEwJ4jE)

Comment: yes it is possible, you will always have some kind of instability but you can avoid the ones that destroy the ores. also try adding negative effects that you can tolerate, such as charged -- they will add some stability. I managed to create an age with dense ores that is free of decay, crumble and meteors this way. btw, blindness combined with eternal dusk makes an awesome horizon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition, the Dense Ores symbol adds instability, and instability leads to decay. There might be a way to remove the instability through cheating, but that is, as stated previously, cheating.

Your best bet would be to have a chicken, cow, and sugarcane farm, so that you can make the books that you need. Once you get Dense Ores symbol, you can learn the symbol in the [Writing Desk](http://technicpack.wikia.com/wiki/Writing_Desk), and then write the Dense Ores symbol into any age you want to.

Comment: Seems you're right... even when I describe an age perfectly (instability value of 0), I still get debuffs and presumably the decay bubbling somewhere. Makes sense for the game balance though. Oh well.

Comment: @lunboks MINE QUICKLY!

Comment: @SevenSidedDie S'kind of difficult when you have mining fatigue, blindness, and meteors dropping through the ceiling.

Comment: @lunboks It's true. Not all unstable ages manifest instability the same way though, so you might get lucky and write one that "just" has debuffs (which are supposed to only affect you when you're under the sky) and decay.

Answer (score 3):

You can counteract the Dense Ores symbol by adding the Charged symbol to the age a few times.  You will likely get some debuffs as well, but Decay is now limited to the more unstable ages, and the less unstable ages are generally safe except for the potion effects.

I don't know if you'd count this as cheating or not, but you can view an age's instabilities by opening its agedata.dat file with NBTEdit. The agedata file is located at (save name)/data/agedata_(age ID).dat.

If you don't see one of the Decays listed, it's safe to inhabit.

Comment: I have ages with obvious decay in them and yet their NBT file says nothing about that except `InstabilityEnabled:1` which...every age of mine says :\

Answer (score 1):

Dense ores adds instability but you can turn instability off in the config for mystcraft:

```
instability=false
instability.black_decay=false
```

I think this is what the options are called but once you're in the config it should be obvious.

Comment: Well, that's basically the cheating I mentioned above. Sure, I could do that. I could also just play in creative and dispense with the need for resources.

Answer (score 0):

Anything with too many buffs creates diseased worlds as anything with more than two, maybe three from each category will make it corrupt. The best bet is a flat world with a few biomes on it and a 64x64 quarry so that you can have all the ores you'll ever need.